# Access JSON reply

Tags: javascript, json

I am using Amazon Web Services database dynamodb. It returns a a JSON which looks liek this:

```
{"Responses":{"friends":[{"to_username":"u1","from_username":"u2"}]},"UnprocessedKeys":{}}
```

I need to get the length of the friends array and also get individual values (e.g to_username in the first element of the array which is "u1" in the example).

I have tried something like this:

```
console.log(data.responses.friends.length); //get length (data is the object I get returned from my async call
console.log(data.responses.friends.to_username[0]); //get to_username of the first element in the array
```

Both return undefined.

Comment: `responses != Responses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case matters!

```
console.log(data.Responses.friends.length); //get length (data is the object I get returned from my async call
console.log(data.Responses.friends.to_username[0]); //get to_username of the first element in the array
```

produces the correct results. Note the uppercase R in Responses.

Comment: O my gosh, I spent over an hour trying to figure out what is wrong. Thank you so much it works now! What a dummy I am!

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a [case sensitive](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch02_02.htm) language. Please ensure the case in your code matches with the case in your response.